# for loop to find correlations between same variables (columns) in 2 different dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes: CNA and mrna_zscores. I'm trying to use this for loop to find correlations between same variables (columns) in the two dataframes but it returns an empty vector (NULL)... what is going wrong?

```
for(i in 1:50){
   cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall <- cor(CNA[, i], mrna_zscores[, i], method = "kendall")
}
```

I got the result I wanted but with a lot of code, not very useful...

```
cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall <- c(cor(CNA[, 1], mrna_zscores[, 1], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 2], mrna_zscores[, 2], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 3], mrna_zscores[, 3], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 4], mrna_zscores[, 4], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 5], mrna_zscores[, 5], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 6], mrna_zscores[, 6], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 7], mrna_zscores[, 7], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 8], mrna_zscores[, 8], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 9], mrna_zscores[, 9], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 10], mrna_zscores[, 10], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 11], mrna_zscores[, 11], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 12], mrna_zscores[, 12], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 13], mrna_zscores[, 13], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 14], mrna_zscores[, 14], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 15], mrna_zscores[, 15], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 16], mrna_zscores[, 16], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 17], mrna_zscores[, 17], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 18], mrna_zscores[, 18], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 19], mrna_zscores[, 19], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 20], mrna_zscores[, 20], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 21], mrna_zscores[, 21], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 22], mrna_zscores[, 22], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 23], mrna_zscores[, 23], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 24], mrna_zscores[, 24], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 25], mrna_zscores[, 25], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 26], mrna_zscores[, 26], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 27], mrna_zscores[, 27], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 28], mrna_zscores[, 28], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 29], mrna_zscores[, 29], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 30], mrna_zscores[, 30], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 31], mrna_zscores[, 31], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 32], mrna_zscores[, 32], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 33], mrna_zscores[, 33], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 34], mrna_zscores[, 34], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 35], mrna_zscores[, 35], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 36], mrna_zscores[, 36], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 37], mrna_zscores[, 37], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 38], mrna_zscores[, 38], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 39], mrna_zscores[, 39], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 40], mrna_zscores[, 40], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 41], mrna_zscores[, 41], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 42], mrna_zscores[, 42], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 43], mrna_zscores[, 43], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 44], mrna_zscores[, 44], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 45], mrna_zscores[, 45], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 46], mrna_zscores[, 46], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 47], mrna_zscores[, 47], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 48], mrna_zscores[, 48], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 49], mrna_zscores[, 49], method = "kendall"), cor(CNA[, 50], mrna_zscores[, 50], method = "kendall"))
```

Why am I not using cor function without the brackets after the dataframe names? Well it returns to me the correlations like this: V1xV1, V1xV2, V1xV3... V2xV1, V2xV2, V2xV3... V3xV1, V3xv2, V3xV3...

All I want is a vector with V1xV1, V2xV2, V3xV3.

Comment: `cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall <- c(cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall, cor(mrna_zscores[, i], CNA.....)`. Be sure to initiate the variable **outside** of the loop beforehand i.e. `cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall <- c()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to create a variable to populate.

```
correlations<-data.frame()
for(i in 1:50){
   cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall <- cor(CNA[, i], mrna_zscores[, i], method = "kendall")
   correlations<-rbind(correlations,cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall)
}
```

Comment: I used your code and really worked. But I can't understand why I have to use create a variable outside the loop and use rbind with cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall...
Why can't I just write
    `cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall <- data.frame() #line
    for(i in 1:50){ #line
       cor_CNA_mRNA_kendall <- cor(CNA[, i], mrna_zscores[, i], method = "kendall") #line
                  }`

Comment: @HanjoJo'burgOdendaal, your code works, but you're iteratively growing the correlations `data.frame`. In R this is a very bad practice. It is better to preallocate the matrix/`data.frame` before running your for loop. For example, `corr <- data.frame(ans = rep(NA, nrow(CNA)); for(i in 1:ncol(CNA){corr$ans[i] <- cor(CNA[, i], mrna_zscores[, i], method = "kendall")}`  Read this to understand why, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Comment: @JacobH, you are definitely correct in saying that pre-allocation is better to do. Usually do it by using matrix(ncol, nrow). Didnt know you could do the same for data.frame. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As is usually the case in R, the best way to do this is without the use of a for loop.  What you are essentially after is the diagonal of the variance-covariance matrix.  Therefore you should focus your efforts on extracting the diagonal.

#### Using Base R

```
d1 <- matrix(sample(100), 10, 10)
d2 <- matrix(sample(100), 10, 10)

cor(d1, d2, method = "kendall")[as.logical(diag(nrow(d1)))]
```

#### Using OpenMx package

```
library(OpenMx)

diag2vec(cor(d1, d2, method = "kendall"))
```